# Let Selenium Render JS Data and Scrape?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Lets say I have a web page like this:

`https://store.playstation.com/en-gb/product/EP0002-CUSA24267_00-CODCWSTANDARD001`

When rendered in a normal browser, this text appears:

[image]

However, when using selenium like this: https://pastebin.com/raw/MUkeMWhK

The javascript does not seem to render, it actually just shows this:

[image]

Adding a print statement just shows an object

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="2cfa798e8ae12131f8ad97de7f9d53af", element="92ba9953-0cd4-4f00-a560-42eb4b556348")>
```

How would I be able to get the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
url = "https://store.playstation.com/en-gb/product/EP0002-CUSA24267_00-CODCWSTANDARD001"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get(url)

try:
    prodPageDealLength = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.preorder-timer'))
    )
    print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".preorder-timer").text )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'preorder-timer)]").text)
```

It should print the text of the preorder div class.